# Web Application Infrastructure and Configuration

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, server

I am working on a project where the requirement is as follows:

It's in the initial stage so was just looking to get an answer if this is possible or not.

1. Client has their desktop application which has MSSQL database in their local Windows Server 2012.
2. The desktop application has its limitations because they would like to have some data capturing done by users which would directly go into their application's MSSQL database. And the desktop application does not provide any web based API.
3. We proposed a web application which will be on PHP & MySQL which would be on their local Windows Server 2012.
4. The MySQL database will sync data to MSSQL database bi-directionally using third party software.
5. As the Windows Server is their local server, I would like a way where normal users can access my PHP application through internet.
6. Windows server has Sonic Firewall so would like to know how we can configure the server which would allow internet users to access application which resides in their local server through internet without jeopardizing the security aspects.

Apologies if I was not clear in something but this is something new to me to just trying to get my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you do it that why but i want to suggest to remove the MySQL database and the synchronisation tool between databases, you can directly interact with MSSQL from PHP.

[Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sa/download/details.aspx?id=20098)

After you will need to configure a rule for your 80 port on this server to be accessible from Internet.

[image]